# Ignore Wait step timeout in CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

Is there a way in casperjs to ignore a timeout for a specific event? I know there is an `onStepTimeout` function but I believe it is for all step timeouts. I have a loop doing a refresh and don't care if it times out versus the other steps. Any way to flag or ignore timeout based on the step it is performing?

Edit:  here is my code snippet. I got it working using a global variable flag but don't know if this the correct way:

```js
//flag
var tout="yes";

//onStepTimeout function
  onStepTimeout: function(self,m) {
    console.log('List Detection: Process step timed out.');
    if ( tout == "yes" ) {
      this.exit();
    }
  },


//Event I dont want to skip if timeout
tout="no";
casper.thenOpen('https://url/account/gotoLogin.action', function() {
  //...
});


//Event I do want to skip if timeout
tout="yes";
casper.thenOpen('https://url/browse/browse.action', function() {
  //...
});
```

Comment: Can you post your current code? Either the snippet in question, or a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this with a global variable, but you missed that `casper.then*` only schedules the steps and does not execute them. You need to move the global variable inside a step to assure that it is flipped at the right time.

```js
//flag
var mayExit = true;

function addMayExitStep(newMayExit){
    casper.then(function(){
        mayExit = newMayExit;
    });
}

//onStepTimeout function
  onStepTimeout: function(self,m) {
    console.log('List Detection: Process step timed out.');
    if ( mayExit ) {
      this.exit();
    }
  },

//Event I dont want to skip if timeout
addMayExitStep(false);
casper.thenOpen('https://url/account/gotoLogin.action', function() {
  //...
});


//Event I do want to skip if timeout
addMayExitStep(true);
casper.thenOpen('https://url/browse/browse.action', function() {
  //...
});
```